# MySQL Table rename and Grants

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.0, permissions

We are in the process of spring-cleaning our production MySQL 5.0 database, and this includes the renaming a number of tables.

We are using the following syntax for the rename

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`table_a`
RENAME TO `mydb`.`table_b`
```

The expected behaviour would be that the GRANTS for `table_a` would be shifted across to `table_b`.  This does not seem to be the case.

Assuming that what we see is correct is there a simple solution we can add to our scripting?

It looks like we should be able to update the `TABLE_PRIVILEGES.TABLE_NAME` column in the information schema, but we are assuming that whilst reading the schema is OK, we shouldn't be manually updating it.

Which leads to reading `TABLE_PRIVILEGES` and Granting / Revoking privileges line by line...

Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Have ended up Querying information_schema.Table_Privileges and scripting Grants & Revokes based on the result.